# Store multiple nodes to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to using Firebase and Android Studio and I need multiple nodes to save to a realtime database in Firebase from my android app, these include users, budgets and spending as it's an expense tracking app. I've got the user information to save under its own node but I can't figure out how to create nodes for budget and spending. The code below is what I'm having difficulty with :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
    setupUIViews();
    firebaseAuth = getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    btn_subCat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(validate()){
                sendUserBudgets();
                Toast.makeText(Categories.this, "Completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(Categories.this, Menu.class ));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Categories.this, "Submission failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void setupUIViews() {
    travel_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.travel_input);
    entertainment_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entertainment_input);
    fitness_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fitness_input);
    beauty_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.beauty_input);
    clothes_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.clothes_input);
    holiday_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.holiday_input);
    food_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.food_input);
    mobile_input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile_input);
    btn_subCat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_subCat);

}

private Boolean validate() {
    boolean result = false;
    travel_budget = Double.parseDouble(travel_input.getText().toString().trim());
    entertainment_budget = Double.parseDouble(entertainment_input.getText().toString().trim());
    fitness_budget = Double.parseDouble(fitness_input.getText().toString().trim());
    beauty_budget = Double.parseDouble(beauty_input.getText().toString().trim());
    clothes_budget = Double.parseDouble(clothes_input.getText().toString().trim());
    holiday_budget = Double.parseDouble(holiday_input.getText().toString().trim());
    food_budget = Double.parseDouble(food_input.getText().toString().trim());
    mobile_budget = Double.parseDouble(mobile_input.getText().toString().trim());

    if(travel_budget.equals(null) || entertainment_budget.equals(null) || fitness_budget.equals(null) || beauty_budget.equals(null) || clothes_budget.equals(null) || holiday_budget.equals(null) || food_budget.equals(null) ||
            mobile_budget.equals(null)){
        Toast.makeText(Categories.this, "Please enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

private void sendUserBudgets() {
    String currentUserID = firebaseAuth.getUid();
    CategoriesDB catDb = new CategoriesDB(travel_budget, entertainment_budget, fitness_budget, beauty_budget, clothes_budget, holiday_budget, food_budget, mobile_budget);
    mDatabase.child("User").child(currentUserID).child("Budgets").setValue(catDb);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work when you run this code? Specifically: when you step through this code in the debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Log to see if t he currentUserID returned by getUid() actually exists within your database.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the OnClickListener, the validation isn't working and the information isn't being stored under a new node in Firebase, but thank you for your help! I checked the Log and the unique ID from Firebase is being stored in the database! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void validate() {
    boolean result = false;
    travel_budget = Double.parseDouble(travel_input.getText().toString().trim());
    entertainment_budget = Double.parseDouble(entertainment_input.getText().toString().trim());
    fitness_budget = Double.parseDouble(fitness_input.getText().toString().trim());
    beauty_budget = Double.parseDouble(beauty_input.getText().toString().trim());
    clothes_budget = Double.parseDouble(clothes_input.getText().toString().trim());
    holiday_budget = Double.parseDouble(holiday_input.getText().toString().trim());
    food_budget = Double.parseDouble(food_input.getText().toString().trim());
    mobile_budget = Double.parseDouble(mobile_input.getText().toString().trim());

    if(travel_budget.equals(null) || entertainment_budget.equals(null) || fitness_budget.equals(null) || beauty_budget.equals(null) || clothes_budget.equals(null) || holiday_budget.equals(null) || food_budget.equals(null) ||
            mobile_budget.equals(null)){
        Toast.makeText(Categories.this, "Please enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        sendUserBudgets(travel_budget, fitness_budget, beauty_budget, clothes_budget, holiday_budget, food_budget, mobile_budget);
    }
}

private void sendUserBudgets(double travel_budget, double fitness_budget, double beauty_budget, double clothes_budget, double holiday_budget, doublefood_budget, double mobile_budget) {
    String currentUserID = firebaseAuth.getUid();
    CategoriesDB catDb = new CategoriesDB(travel_budget, entertainment_budget, fitness_budget, beauty_budget, clothes_budget, holiday_budget, food_budget, mobile_budget);
    mDatabase.child("User").child(currentUserID).child("Budgets").setValue(catDb);
}
```

Here once you have obtained all the user inputs and have done all the validations, you need to call the function `sendUserBudgets()` to save it to the database.

Comment: I still can't get it to work, I'm thinking there is a problem with the OnClickListener! Thank you for your help! :)